# Visible space character disappears in listings with xelatex

Tags: xetex, pdftex, listings

With TeX Live 2019 (manual install), this is my code:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi
%
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,showstringspaces=true,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
# un commentaire
i = 1
while i <= 5:
  print(i)
  i = i + 1
print('Fini !')
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

With pdflatex, the visible space before `!` in `'Fini !'` appears. With xelatex, it disappears...

On TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian, it appairs with both, pdflatex and xelatex...

How to obtain the visual space with xelatex on TeX Live 2019?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, in this case it's `listings` that tries to use `\char32`, which in the OT font has no suitable glyph for the purpose.

Comment: thanks to egreg, i'll try his solution by this day. But why this difference between TL2015 and TL2019 ?

Comment: Until 2018, `fontspec` redefined `\lst@visiblespace`, but the most recent version no longer does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `\lst@visiblespace` makes `listings` typeset `\char32` when the font family is `\ttdefault`, but the OTF version of Latin Modern Mono hasn't a visible space there.

```latex
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <- don't forget
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\ifxetex
  \makeatletter
  \def\lst@visiblespace{\lst@ttfamily{\char"2423}\textvisiblespace}
  \makeatother
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,showstringspaces=true,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
# un commentaire
i = 1
while i <= 5:
  print(i)
  i = i + 1
print('Fini !')
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I use the same character used by `\textvisiblespace`, that is, U+2423 OPEN BOX.

With a recent version of LaTeX (October 2019), a better patch would be

```latex
\def\lst@visiblespace{\lst@ttfamily\verbvisible\textvisiblespace}
```

that doesn't even need to be conditionally performed.

[image]

---

Up to 2018, `fontspec` used to patch `\lst@visiblespace`, making it equal to `\fontspec_visible_space:`. The last version doesn't, but it's probably a mistake. Here's how to reinstate the better code:

```latex
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\ifxetex
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_set_eq:cN { lst@visiblespace } \fontspec_visible_space:
  \ExplSyntaxOff
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,showstringspaces=true,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
# un commentaire
i = 1
while i <= 5:
  print(i)
  i = i + 1
print('Fini !')
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be wrong to use `\DeclareRobustCommand\verbvisiblespace{{\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont\char"2423}}
\def\lst@visiblespace{\verbvisiblespace}`?

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Yes: you'd be hard coding `lmtt`.

Comment: If the distribution is totally updated you can change the package `ifxetex` to `iftex`, from my point of view I think it is not always good to leave `\verbvisiblespace\textvisiblespace`, if you change the main font of the document (libertine for example), the character is very small, it is better to define directly `\verbvisiblespace`.

Comment: thanks to egreg. It's word.